# Swift Fade In Animation for Background Animation between A Single View to a PageView Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

So I am trying to create a fade in animation for a UI Image that is in a page view scroller after a button is clicked in the main view controller. This is my main storyboard.

```
class MainWorkoutViewController: UIViewController {
    // Outlet used in storyboard
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();


        func scrollViewDidEndDragging(MainWorkoutViewController: UIScrollView,
            withVelocity: CGPoint,
            targetContentOffset : UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){

        }

        // 1) Create the three views used in the swipe container view
        var AVc :AViewController =  AViewController(nibName: "AViewController", bundle: nil);
        var BVc :BViewController =  BViewController(nibName: "BViewController", bundle: nil);
        var CVc :CViewController =  CViewController(nibName: "CViewController", bundle: nil);


        // 2) Add in each view to the container view hierarchy
        //    Add them in opposite order since the view hieracrhy is a stack
        self.addChildViewController(CVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(CVc.view);
        CVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(BVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(BVc.view);
        BVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(AVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(AVc.view);
        AVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);


        // 3) Set up the frames of the view controllers to align
        //    with eachother inside the container view
        var adminFrame :CGRect = BVc.view.frame;

        adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.width;
        AVc.view.frame = adminFrame;

        var BFrame :CGRect = AVc.view.frame;
        BFrame.origin.x = 2*BFrame.width;
        CVc.view.frame = BFrame;


        // 4) Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
        var scrollWidth: CGFloat  = 3 * self.view.frame.width
        var scrollHeight: CGFloat  = self.view.frame.size.height
        self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight)
        var frame: CGRect = self.view.frame
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(1);
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        self.scrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: false)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
    }
}
```

This is the .swift file for the first Viewcontroller that I have, which contains the image I want to fade in when the screen loads.

```
import UIKit

class AViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Background: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
            self.Background.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I looked around for a way to do it and that is why I have the animatedWithDuration, but instead all I am getting is the screen swiping up from the bottom of the phone. Any ideas?

Comment: what effect are you trying to achieve? viewDidAppear is not called after you have scrolled to a view in the scrollview. it is called when the view is added to the hierarchy. you have to manually write the code for making the label appear using scrollView delegate functions

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the alpha to `0.0` before the `UIView.animateWithDuration` function.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.background.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
        self.background.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

Please note that `viewDidAppear` is not called after you have scrolled to a view in the scrollview. It is called when the `view` is added to the `view hierarchy`. You have to manually write the code for making the label appear using scrollView delegate functions if you want to make it appear when you scroll with your fingers or scroll automatically later.

You can do a cross dissolve animation instead of scrolling by doing

```
CATransaction.flush()

self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width,0)
UIView.transitionWithView(self.scrollView, duration: 1.0, options:
    .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
     }) { (finished) -> Void in

}
```

Either use `CATransactionFlush` or put the code inside `viewDidAppear`.
Remove the `scrollView.scrollRectToVisible` code.

Comment: So when I input this, it does fade in but only after it slides up. Is there a way to override this too?

Comment: you said "it does fade in but only after it slides up". so what else do you want it to do?

Comment: Not slide up at all. Just dissolve from one screen to the next. I have a pattern I set up and the screens have the same pattern but different colors. So I am trying to create an effect where they look like colors are just dissolving into one another

Comment: are you sure you want to use a scrollview?

Comment: The main view is my login screen that goes to a scrollview where I have other screens. The transition is between the main login screen and the scrollview.

Comment: Any idea in how to not have the page slide up rather just dissolve in?